# How to deal with two mail binaries?

Tags: bash, alias, smtp

I recently installed both msmtp (smtp client) and mailutils on an M1 iMac via MacPorts. I couldn't get msmtp to work until I realized that there were two mail binaries on the machine, one that, I guess, is native and one installed by mailutils:

```
Valentine:~ mnewman$ which -a mail
/opt/local/bin/mail
/usr/bin/mail
```

Unfortunately, the wrong one was being used if I tried to send mail from the Command line which caused msmtp to fail. I tried to fix it with:

```
Valentine:~ mnewman$ alias mail="/usr/bin/mail"
Valentine:~ mnewman$ type mail
mail is aliased to `/usr/bin/mail'
```

Which works, but I think there must be a better way. Is there?

Edited to show why I need to use /usr/bin/mail rather than /opt/local/bin/mail with msmtp:

```
Valentine:~ mnewman$ /opt/local/bin/mail me@mac.com
Cc:
Subject: none
test
msmtp: no recipients found
Sending data to /opt/local/bin/msmtp failed: Process exited with a non-zero status
cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
Valentine:~ mnewman$ /usr/bin/mail me@mac.com
Subject: none
test
EOT
```

/opt/local/bin/mail fails while /usr/bin/mail works

Comment: You could chnage your path so /usr/bin is before /opt/local/bin but that means taht all Apple binaries are found before the MacPorts ones but I think that normally you want the Macports ones so the side effects could be wrong. In your case why install mailutils if you don't want its mail?

Comment: I didn't change the path for the reason you state. I installed mailutils because it was stated as being required for msmtp. I tried uninstalling mailutils and then msmtp wouldn't work at all. I don't really understand why. --  Here's what Mailutils contains: 

GNU Mailutils is a rich and powerful protocol-independent mail framework. It contains a series of useful mail libraries, clients, and servers. This package contains the GNU mailutils versions of dotlock, frm, from, maidag, mail, messages, mimeview, movemail, readmsg and sieve. --

No idea which one of those msmtp requires.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do rather than use an alias or change the PATH order is create a shell script called mail and put that in a directory before either of the mail executables. I would put /usr/local/bin and/or a local bin ~/bin or nowadays ~/.local/bin at the front of the path. This script will then act like any other executable and be available to any other program just like your current mail executables, whilst an alias is just a text replacement when you type mail at the beginning of a command.

The mail script would be like - note this is totally untested.
It calls explicitly the executable you want and passes all the command line arguments to this.

```bash
#! /bin/sh
/usr/bin/mail $@
```

Comment: The only reason is that msmtp doesn't work with the GNU mail but does work with the BSD mail. I don't know why. If I used the GNU mail I would get this error: msmtp: no recipients found - Sending data to /opt/local/bin/msmtp failed: Process exited with a non-zero status. But, it works fine with BSD mail. It's a mystery to me. The only time I really use mail is within shell scripts in which I always use the full path to mail. I was only using it from the command line to verify that msmtp was working.

Comment: I edited the original question to show why I need to use the BSD version of mail rather than the GNU version.

Comment: I have removed my query - however I would not that asking why GNU mail does not work here would be a good question. It is on topic here but I suspect Super User or Unix & Linux might have more people who use non Apple mail setup

Comment: I've seen no mention of this issue elsewhere. Anyone who installed msmtp from MacPorts along with mailutils would have had the same problem. So, I have to conclude that's it's a mistake I made somewhere. I made the author of msmtp aware of the issue and he chose not to deal with it.